# R linprog delivers incorrect solution

Tags: r, linear-programming

I am solving the following simple linear program with pracma::linprog in R:

```
library(pracma)

cc=c(1)
A=as.matrix(-1)
b=c(1)

linprog(cc,A,b,maximize=FALSE)
```

The solution returned is `x=0`.

However, this solution is incorrect: a lower value of the linear program can clearly be obtained at `x=-1`.

I find that both Wolfram Alpha and Matlab return the correct solution.

Why does linprog return the wrong solution? Is there any way to correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From `?linprog`

> This is a first version that will be unstable at times. For real
> linear programming problems use package lpSolve

Which gives the same answer

```
lpSolve::lp(direction='min', cc,A,"<=",b)
Success: the objective function is 0
```

And from `?lp`

```
Note that every variable is assumed to be >= 0!
```